# Force errors to use exit code 0

Tags: php, phpunit

In someone of my tests a class import was forgotten and when run `phpunit` show:

> Class 'Tests\Unit\MyClass' not found

But this error was thrown with `exit code 0`, checking the output `echo $?`.

The problem is that exit code `0` makes the `CI` successful.

`phpunit.xml` contains:

```xml
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
        beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-9.5.phar
```

```
$ cat Test.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class Test extends TestCase
{
    public function testOne(): void
    {
        new DoesNotExist;
    }
}
```

```
$ php phpunit-9.5.phar Test.php
PHPUnit 9.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.001, Memory: 18.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Test::testOne
Error: Class "DoesNotExist" not found

/home/sb/Test.php:8

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

```
$ echo $?                       
2
```